# Do Spring MVC need unit test or just integration test

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, integration-testing

I'm creating Rest API using Spring Boot (spring mvc, spring-hateoas, spring data jpa, spring-security).

Right now, i start refactoring my code also try to increase code coverage.

What i want to ask, in my controller (Spring MVC) should i write unit test or i just can go with integration test (skip unit test)?

Answer (score 0):

All that controllers should do is to delegate work to proper service. They should not contain any logic, so IMHO unit tests are not required. I always test controllers by writing integration tests (they test all layers of application - from controller to data storage layer).

Comment: Thank for your response Karol, 
You said all logic should contain at service layer. 
How about validation logic? i have two cases here :
1. check if the return from the service is null and then throw NotFoundException to produce 404. 
2. check if user already exists in database. 
Where should this validation placed? controller or service layer?